# dynamic table name in redshift

Tags: dynamic, amazon-redshift

I have a few tables with similar names but different prefixes: us_cities, ca_cities and uk_cities.
Each one of those tables consist only one column (City_name). I want to union all those tables together and get a result like that:

```
select 'US' as country, City_name from US_cities
union all
select 'CA' as country, City_name from CA_cities
union all
select 'UK' as country, City_name from UK_cities
```

In the future I will have more city tables for more countries and I want a dynamic query/view that will identify the relevant tables (*_cities) and add them in the union query. How can I do that in Redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `information_schema.tables` table to get a list of the tables that  match your naming convention. However you would need an external process to replace your view.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%_cities';
```

IMHO, you'd be much better off having a single `cities` table and using views to create the country specific versions. :)

Comment: That's exactly how I understood I should do it. Sadly I'm talking about 3rd party tables that they manage so I get them separately.
thanks